# How to get root privileges from process

Tags: linux, root, privileges

It's possible to get root privileges by simple code like this:

```
char *name[2];
name[0] = "/bin/bash";
name[1] = "-p";
name[2] = 0x0;

execve(name[0], name, 0x0);
```

but this solution requires to set sticky bit chown root:root; chmod u+s.

The question is how to get root privileges only by providing user name and password (by process and to this process, - so process asking user for login information and use this permission to execution).

Comment: Which version of Linux?

Comment: Solution shall work on all of the modern Linux environments since RHEL 4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue is solved by providing a root passphrase directly to su utility. It can be easily riched by using fd_set or pipes and system call forkpty that returns a ready to login shell.

Please check my post that describe this question and shows a solution: 
http://www.andreypudov.com/2013/02/user-authorization-in-linux.html